# How to access all of the subdirectory wordpress with Reverse Proxy?

Tags: wordpress, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have some issues with my Wordpress on Reverse Proxy.

So far, here is my simple nginx config.

```
 server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  site1.abc;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP             $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.45:8009/;
    }
```

My wp-config.php

```
/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4' );

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         ' N=R*yg% {?,:u*%P?b|B@.#]No Eco`%Wr>T5_6LAPaY#|T%A4%n2Eb>6b4M-F+' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'bYNdT{ !4lw&j@7FCylQx{ 1rc(|{Lvq9MzVYgWt1EZ?Udm~ wvXd,Eq:O ~N,D3' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '/PY2ks,|10T7*^K|?R bM<`5O3$w%f <Xk)YT.aF5ZWHyLD%ju5v`O_12W&GzLsz' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        '{B+Fpx]pUzgU(pMgDUm84AaHApsvh.p*2:+Y>7>f1uBR=Omz,s`D}8CW{?sr7Xy&' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        '~?+>T0E+>)E{tje{MV(![Fi74B.,iMG5.1cdg`>fzYF[!]/)7&{J[(Ix<NB-zs*%' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '/J=VF|:Tm%Hk!>b51QMX?f{~,xG6v9$`!OhY)W- rw`vi>,,?}zWB5Ap|DMe?wQu' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'MM~^^0ERsgDJqDv=73EXIhWrmN0*{C*GKm0%5 c((6T-f!P/5e;qsIg%Ss:@1i.H' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       ',A#EHnqxe13pe3i-/LTLWs3GAK?MRa4^B>aV`Pg+ZjlpMCrEz]%odO 11.3:uBq>' );

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the documentation.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

With my server_name domain has an public IP Address and proxy_pass IP is my internal IP.

It works, but only the homepage. With everthing I click on my homepage it automatically redirect me to my Internal IP that external users cannot access it.

Ex: Click on "About", redirect me to http://192.168.1.45/index.php/blog( give me an error: "This site can’t be reached").

I want: Click on "About", redirect me to http://site1.abc/index.php/blog, something like that.

It doesn't hide my backend server. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Wordpress does not know it is at `site1.abc` and guesses it is at `192.168.1.45` because it receives requests with this address *and no host*.

Make Nginx tell Wordpress that the request is for the `site1.abc` host, so Wordpress knows its own hostname : add the `Host` header to the requests Nginx proxies to Wordpress.

```
location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP             $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass         http://192.168.1.45:8009/;
            proxy_set_header   Host                  site1.abc
    }
```